# Как найти среднее значение каждых четырех элементов массива?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, анализ-данных

Как из этого:

```
    Time  Value1  Value2
0    10     30.5    21.6
1    11      11     50.2
2    13      13     13.33
3    15     101.1    2
4    23       5      5
5    4      11.1     10
6    5      15.1    13.2
7    10      11      2.3
```

Во всех столбцах кроме `Time` надо взять первые 4 строки, найти их среднее:

```
    Time  Value1  Value2
0    15    38,9    21,7825
1    10    10,55   7,625
```

Обычные перебор циклом не подходит, т.к. реальных данных гораздо больше и простой перебор — очень долго.

Есть ли возможность сделать это быстрее и компактнее?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
res = (df
       .groupby(np.arange(len(df)) // 4)
       .agg({"Time": "last", "Value1": "mean", "Value2": "mean"}))
```

---

Результат:

```
    Time    Value1  Value2
0   15      38.90   21.7825
1   10      10.55   7.6250
```